# Paging on the database server with Telerik MVC Extensions Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

Telerik [mention](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serverbinding) this feature:

> Linq based expression engine for pushing grid operations (paging, sorting, filtering and grouping) to the database server

But how to enable it? The examples all take IEnumerable of something or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you're sending the data to the view.  If leave the linq query as lazy evaluated, then you'll the paging will happen on the database.  However, if in your data layer you do a ToList() or other enumeration, you'll be missing out on that, pulling all the data, and will have to set something up to manually page it.

To better show...

```
// In your initial page load
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyViewModel
    {
        // ... other view data

        // set order or .Where for initial load, but don't use .ToList or enumerate
        MyObjects = _db.MyObjects.OrderBy(m => m.Name)
        // When this is passed into the grid, it will finalize the paging there
        // and when the grid enumerates MyObjects, it will only pull the relevant
        // items from the database.
    });
}
```

If you're using ajax binding...

```
// In an ajax grid responder action
[GridAction]
public ActionResult AjaxGridAction()
{
    // Assuming _db is a CodeFirst DbContext, GridModel will handle filtering,
    // paging, and sorting in the database as linq applies those methods to the
    // IQueryable _db.MyObjects
    return View(new GridModel(_db.MyObjects));
}
```

If you are using a repository pattern (although DbContext is already a repository really), then have it return lazy objects:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMyObjects()
{
    // Don't use ToList or enumerate them in your repository - that will
    // pull all the data before the Telerik grid has filtered it.
    return _db.MyObjects;
}
```

Even though everything passes around IEnumerable, when it comes time to actually iterate through the collection, the concrete type (DbSet in the examples above) will be what actually handles that.

If you're using something like AutoMapper, beware that it's very easy to accidentally pull all the records during mapping.  AutoMapper 2 has a solution for projecting out of the database without iterating, but no documentation up yet.  I've been using [this solution for that](https://gist.github.com/1119157) until I have time to investigate AutoMapper 2 more.

```
_db.MyObjects.Project().To<MyObjectsViewModel>();
```

Basically wraps auto-projects properties instead of doing this:

```
_db.MyObjects
    .Select(o => new MyObjectsViewModel { // manually map properties, ewww });
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess they check whether the IEnumerable is an IQueryable under the covers. Explains it. Cheers, Pete.

Comment: They don't really have to check - that's the joy of Linq. The concrete of the IEnumerable will be the one that does the paging. In the Telerik code they just use a .Skip(page).Take(pageSize). The concrete implementor, DbSet or some other IQueryable, is responsible for actually translating that into SQL.  Since Linq is lazy evaluated, until a .ToList or other .To__, the collection being passed into the grid hasn't been pulled yet and can be paged in the dtabase. The Telerik code will call the same code regardless of whatever the concrete type is, and it doesn't have to do anything different.

Comment: You're confusing lazy evaluation with code quotation (expression trees). For example, db.Customers.AsEnumerable().Take(10) will still get all the customers from the database. Looking briefly at the source code, Telerik check whether the IEnumerable is already an IQueryable in Telerik.Web.Mvc.Infrastructure.QueryableFactory.

Answer (score 0):

For a server paging/ordering you should setup **GridOperationMode.Server** prop.

There is a sample of using :

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<PartnerUserViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid").DataBinding(binding =>    binding.Ajax().OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Server).Select("GetUsers", "Partner")).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Representer).Title("Representer");  
    });          
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.OrderBy(sortOrder => sortOrder.Add(p => p.DateCreated).Descending()))
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(pager => pager.Position(GridPagerPosition.Both).PageSize(5))
    .Groupable()
```